# I can't use the Xamarin.Essentials RequestPermissionsAsync

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, blazor

I am trying to request the user of a mobile app the necessary permissions to access the contacts, but when calling the Xamarin.Essentials method, it tells me that `Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions` does not have a definition for `RequestPermissionsAsync`

I tried:

```cs
var status = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions
    .RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.ContactsRead);
```

Comment: You can update the version of `Xamarin.Essentials` and make sure you add the `using Xamarin.Essentials`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();
```

Unless you have an older version of Xamarin Essentials, the latest documentation of [Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android#requesting-permissions) would also agree that there is no such thing as RequestPermissionsAsync.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have tried it and it worked correctly. Thank you!